# php str_replace function issue

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I am trying to have this ORIGINAL string converted to the RESULT below using php.

```
ORIGINAL: "The quick <font color="brown">brown</font> fox jumps over the lazy dog"

RESULT:"god yzal eht revo spmuj xof <font color="brown">nworb</font> kciuq ehT"
```

What I have done so far is explained like below.

First, strip the HTML tag from the ORIGINAL.

```
$originalStr = "The quick <font color='brown'>brown</font> fox jumps over the lazy dog";

$stripTags = strip_tags($originalStr);
```

**This results to The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog** ,

Second, I reverse the result and the word "brown" by using strrev function

```
$reverseStr = strrev($stripTags);
$brown = strrev("brown");
```

**This results to god yzal eht revo spmuj xof nworb kciuq ehT**

Third, I am trying to use **str_replace function** to find $brown from the reverseStr, and replace it with **$openFont $brown $closeFont** like below.

```
$openFont = "<font color='brown'>";
$closeFont = "</font>";

$result = str_replace($brown, $openFont.$brown.$closeFont, $reverseStr);
echo "result -->" . $result . "<br/><br/><br/>";
```

**This results to god yzal eht revo spmuj xof kciuq ehT**, NOT the same as the RESULT.

It seems like special characters in font () tag is the problem that may be blocking str_replace to replace the String.

```
$result = str_replace($brown, "TEST", $reverseStr);
echo "result -->" . $result . "<br/><br/><br/>";
```

**This results to god yzal eht revo spmuj xof TEST kciuq ehT**

Does anyone know str_replace is not accepting special characters? and know how I should solve this problem?

If there is another way to solve the problem, I will also be appreciated to hear your suggestion.

(* This is one of the practical questions that I am trying to solve in an algorithm test websites)

**UPDATED: I feel so dumb to think that where font tag was. Since  tag is meant to change the font color, it was working perfectly in the beginning. Thank you very much everyone for your time!**

Comment: Special characters in the variable should have nothing to do with the end result. `$openFont = "<font color='brown'>"; $closeFont = "</font>"; $brown = strrev("brown"); $reverseStr = 'god yzal eht revo spmuj xof nworb kciuq ehT'; $result = str_replace($brown, $openFont.$brown.$closeFont, $reverseStr);` works perfectly fine. Make sure there are no other mistakes in the code before this, esp. with declaring the `$reverseStr;` variable.

Comment: Working perfect: https://eval.in/850081

Comment: This feels like one of those awful job-interview whiteboard questions

Answer (score 2):

If it was me, I'd do this (fully tested):

```
// Original string
$str = 'The quick <font color="brown">brown</font> fox jumps over the lazy dog';

// Strip the font tag
$str = strip_tags( $str );

// Convert string to array
$arr = str_split( $str );

// Reverse the array
$rra = array_reverse( $arr );

// Convert array back to string
$str = implode( $rra );

// Add font tag back in
$str = str_replace('nworb', '<font color="brown">nworb</font>', $str);


// Result
echo $str;
```

Comment: I'd probably do it a little differently if I was to do it again, but it was the first thing to pop into my head. Only spent about 2 minutes on it. A more interesting problem might be to reverse a string with unknown tags, in both type and quantity.

Comment: How would you reverse string with unknown tags?  More interesting to think about is what if a user wants to either change the color of the font or use different html tags? Hard coding the <font> tag and put that in a variable would not be the best answer. Don't you think? In this case, do you think I should use regular expression to get the string starting with '<' and ending with '>' and put it in a variable?

Comment: Yes, regular expressions. Imagine what would happen if you had `<br />` tags, or random `<span>` tags. It could be quite challenging.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the HTML with something that will give you a DOM API to it.

Write a function that loops over the child nodes of an element.

If a node is a text node, get the data as a string, split it on words, reverse each one, then assign it back.

If a node is an element, recurse into your function.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use preg_match_all() function.  
$originalStr  = "The quick <font color='brown'>brown</font> fox jumps over the lazy dog";
preg_match_all('|<[^>]+>(.*)</[^>]+>|U', $originalStr, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
$_tag =  $matches[0][0];
$_txt =  $matches[0][1];
$newString = str_replace($_tag,$_txt,$originalStr);
```